# Using if statement to execute different command based on a global variable value

Tags: if-statement, vim

I want to execute `:set winminheight=1<cr>^W=^W_` if the value of variable `winminheight` is `0`.
else I want to run `:set winminheight=0<cr>^W_`

I tried below mapping script to accomplish this but it doesn't work. I get no error either.

```
nnoremap <silent>  <leader>0 
\ : if (&g:winminheight ==0) <BAR>
\   execute "normal! :set winminheight=1""\<lt>cr>^W=^W_" <BAR>
\ else <BAR>
\   execute "normal! :set winminheight=0""\<lt>cr>^W_" <BAR>
\ endif <CR>
```

When I call the mapping, it doesn't respond at all.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Also see [vi.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I follow exactly what you're trying to do...

But some points to take note:

- You don't need `:normal` to run an Ex command such as `set winminheight=0`
- For the Ctrl-W commands, you can also use [`wincmd`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd), which means it's possible to also use Ex commands for those.
- Finally, you don't need the parens around the condition in the `if` statement, and you don't need the `g:` either (`'winminheight'` is a global option.)

Putting it all together:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>0  
\ :if &winminheight == 0 <BAR>
\    set winminheight=1 <BAR>
\    wincmd = <BAR>
\    wincmd _ <BAR>
\ else <BAR>
\    set winminheight=0 <BAR>
\    wincmd _ <BAR>
\ endif <CR>
```

My recommendation is to *strongly* avoid using `:execute` and `:normal` directly from a mapping... Since the mapping itself will expand key sequences already, you end up with multiple levels of escaping and it's really hard to get it right.

I really tried to debug your mapping and after quite a few attempts I got to this solution which you'll see is *very* ugly:

```
execute "normal! :set winminheight=1\<lt>cr>\<lt>c-w>=\<lt>c-w>_" <BAR>
```

(This is only the first `:execute`, but you get the picture.)

Even using the Ex commands only is still tricky since you need the `<BAR>` separators which not always work well with every command...

Much better is to just define a function and have the mapping call the function (or use an `<expr>` mapping), then you don't need to worry about none of that escaping in the function body. Much simpler!